# Jenkins Plugin - Extending Run or Build?

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

Hello I'm new to making Jenkins plugins and I have a quick and easy question, but for some reason seems to be giving me a hard time.

My goal is to store a metric with every build. Currently every build had a duration. I would like every build to also have a memoryUsed metric and I need the save() method to be aware of this metric.

What is the best way to do this? Should I extend Run, Build, or FreeStyleBuild for this? Should I use @Extension?

My alternative to this is to store a map of builds to metrics in my plugin object, but that seems backwards.

I would very much appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!